# Object doesn't support property or method 'addOnKeyPress' in Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2016

I am using same code snippet as in [this walk-through](https://msdn.microsoft.com//en-us/library/mt607648.aspx)  for adding addOnKeyPress event to `name` field of account form. But its pops out `Object doesn't support property or method 'addOnKeyPress'`as error but nothing get done.

I tried but nothing get done. I would like to hear from experts.

**Update: Adding Code**

```
function suggestAccounts() {

    // List of sample account names to suggest
    accounts = [
  { name: 'Blue Yonder Airlines', code: 'A06' },
  { name: 'City Power & Light', code: 'A07' },
  { name: 'Coho Vineyard', code: 'A08' },
  { name: 'Coho Winery', code: 'A09' },
  { name: 'Coho Vineyard & Winery', code: 'A10' },
  { name: 'Contoso, Ltd.', code: 'A11' },
  { name: 'Contoso Pharmaceuticals', code: 'A12' },
  { name: 'Contoso Suites', code: 'A13' },
  { name: 'Consolidated Messenger', code: 'A14' },
  { name: '​Fabrikam, Inc.', code: 'A15' },
  { name: 'Fabrikam Residences', code: 'A16' },
  { name: '​First Up Consultants', code: 'A17' },
  { name: 'Fourth Coffee', code: 'A18' },
  { name: 'Relecloud', code: 'A31' },
  { name: 'School of Fine Art', code: 'A32' },
  { name: 'Southridge Video', code: 'A33' },
  { name: 'Tailspin Toys', code: 'A34' },
  { name: 'Trey Research', code: 'A35' },
  { name: 'The Phone Company', code: 'A36' },
  { name: 'VanArsdel, Ltd.', code: 'A37' },
  { name: 'Wide World Importers', code: 'A38' },
  { name: '​Wingtip Toys', code: 'A39' },
  { name: 'Woodgrove Bank', code: 'A40' }    
    ];

    var keyPressFcn = function (ext) {
        try {
            var userInput = Xrm.Page.getControl("name").getValue();
            resultSet = {
                results: new Array(),
                commands: {
                    id: "sp_commands",
                    label: "Learn More",
                    action: function () {
                        // Specify what you want to do when the user
                        // clicks the "Learn More" link at the bottom
                        // of the auto-completion list.
                        // For this sample, we are just opening a page
                        // that provides information on working with
                        // accounts in CRM.
                        window.open("http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/create-or-edit-an-account.aspx");
                    }
                }
            };

            var userInputLowerCase = userInput.toLowerCase();
            for (i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
                if (userInputLowerCase === accounts[i].name.substring(0, userInputLowerCase.length).toLowerCase()) {
                    resultSet.results.push({
                        id: i,
                        fields: [accounts[i].name]
                    });
                }
                if (resultSet.results.length >= 10) break;
            }

            if (resultSet.results.length > 0) {
                ext.getEventSource().showAutoComplete(resultSet);
            } else {
                ext.getEventSource().hideAutoComplete();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // Handle any exceptions. In the sample code,
            // we are just displaying the exception, if any.
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    Xrm.Page.getControl("name").addOnKeyPress(keyPressFcn);    
}
```

Comment: That code worked for me.  Does your form have the "name" field on it?

Comment: yes, it is on the form.

Comment: How is your event wired up to the form?

Comment: I added suggestAccounts to the onLoad event of the form and do nothing else.

Comment: That should work.  There must be some other issue going on.  Maybe try wiring it up to the contact form (replace both occurrences of "name" in script with "firstname" [make sure firstname is on the form]) to see if you can get it working on that form.

Comment: no luck again. I try creating a custom field then placed on the form. but all in vain

Comment: Double check the version of CRM are you using? Are you on-premise or online? Take a screen shot of the About screen and add to your question - when recreating an edge scenario it helps if we can be sure we are on the exact same version/release/build number as the problem system.

Comment: @Nicknow, I can assure that it is on-premise product and the version is **8.0.0.1088**

Comment: Can you post the full code please? @Polshgiant has already tested and it works - so if it isn't CRM version it must be an error in your code.

Comment: @Nicknow, it is same code as that of given in walkthrough and I just changed field name and these fields are placed at the form.

Comment: Well we know it isn't a bug - the functionality works - so it has to be an error in your code. If you don't share your code how can anyone here _help_ you??

Comment: @Nicknow, question is updated with code snippet.

Comment: Could it be browser issue? Did you try diff browser? One of the blog comment says it's broken still for onpremise. :(

Comment: Another comment in walkthrough says, any lookup is needed on the form to load dependent libraries. Do you have one in your form?