# MS Dynamics CRM 2016 - addOnKeyPress event not working

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2016

I've following code snippet at contact form for `nickname` field of type single line text. I've wired the onKeyPress at onLoad event of the form and tried to debug but every time it throws exception both at on-prem and online environment.

I would like to seek expert opinionon it.

**Code Snippet**

```
function onLoad()
{
    Xrm.Page.getControl("nickname").addOnKeyPress(function(){
    alert("Hello World");
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object doesn't support property or method 'addOnKeyPress' in Dynamics CRM 2016](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889727/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-addonkeypress-in-dynamics-crm-2016)

Answer (score 0):

I am also get same exception message while adding addOnKeyPress event to lookup field. But I tried it for simple text field and its worked. Make sure that you are also applying it for text field or loopup type field.